# It is possible for my Text to display more text underneath when clicked?

Tags: javafx

In my application I am creating a help page and I want to create text that when the text is clicked on it displays more description text underneath and when it the title/question is clicked again it hides the text. This is commonly found on many FAQ pages but I am struggling to find a way to do this on JavaFX.

Comment: Check out `HiddenSidesPane` and `InfoOverlay` from [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always implement it yourself by extending behavior of `Text` class but javafx has [Accordion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Accordion.html) which combined with [TitledPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TitledPane.html) gives functionality that you are looking for.

Example code of how it can be used:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TitledPane tp1 = new TitledPane("Text 1", new Text("Your text goes here....."));
    TitledPane tp2 = new TitledPane("Text 2", new Text("Another text goes here....."));
    TitledPane tp3 = new TitledPane("Text 3", new Text("And yet another text goes here....."));

    Accordion accordion = new Accordion();
    accordion.getPanes().addAll(tp1, tp2, tp3);

    Scene scene = new Scene(accordion, 300, 250);  
    primaryStage.setTitle("AccordionExample");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `TitledPane`s:

```
Map<String, String> questions = new HashMap();
questions.put("Question 1", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur"
        + "adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore"
        + "et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud"
        + " exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo"
        + " consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate"
        + " velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur"
        + " sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui"
        + " officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.");
questions.put("Question 2", "Not answered yet");

VBox content = new VBox();
questions.forEach((key, value) -> {
    Label label = new Label(value);
    TitledPane tp = new TitledPane(key, label);
    tp.setExpanded(false);
    label.setWrapText(true);
    content.getChildren().add(tp);
});
```

You may want to change the style of the title using a CSS stylesheet though by adding the following stylesheet to the scene:

```css
.titled-pane > .title {
    -fx-background-color: transparent transparent transparent;
}
```